# Node.js path.resolve resolving to the wrong directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, istanbul

I am using Istanbul for code coverage, and the tests are being stored in the following location `/private/var/folders/dn/hc21m15s4hx3n6kv_dg31vw80000gn/T/cd99ab02d21597f93f32b367adcf060281e9a734`.

Istanbul is obviously being run inside of node_modules directory. If I log path.resolve inside of my project's directory, in let's say app.js, I get the the project's directory path (`/Users/tyroneavnit/Projects/my-project`).

Why is the former path being resolved to `private/var/folders/....` and how can I fix the issue?

I am running Node on OSX El Capitan.